# WebRtc with nodeJS and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webrtc

WebRTC work only in local subnet but after deploy to Heroku stop working correctly. I can not recieve data.

`const PC_CONFIG = { 'iceServers': [{url:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'} ] };` 
github [code](https://github.com/Vlad1slavIP74/rtc)

Comment: share with us the log of heroku and your deps so user can help you

Answer (score 3):

if you are having issues with Heroku, use the Heroku deploy template listed on the Github Code: [image: Heroku Deploy Template].

If you still have errors, please run `heroku logs --tail` and paste the logs so we can help further.